# java csv file into jtable

Tags: java, csv, jframe, jtable

I've looked at previous questions and I haven't understood.
Im a noobie trying to understand how to read a csv file for example
file.csv

> "coordX","coordY","gender","age"
>
> 100,20,"M",19

into a JTable.
Can someone show me how to create a JTable and add this data into it?

Comment: Like I said I don't understand. I need more indepth help.

Comment: To be honest, I suppose that me and others do not imagine more basic and simpler explanation than this.

Comment: JTable uses a "model" to pull data from.  So it's basically about parsing the file, and then putting the data into the JTable's "model".  Parsing CSV files can get a little complicated... especially since there are many different rules/formats out there.  Some have a byte-order marker and some don't.  Using OpenCSVReader to parse will save you a lot of work if you need to support any CSV file you may want to input...  For more on what is meant by "model" see this wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: For help with the parsing of the file, here's a link to the OpenCSV github:  https://github.com/jlawrie/opencsv/blob/master/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java